# What to return for 'begin' and 'end' functions for my vector wrapper, for iterators?

Tags: c++

I have a class called `PointList`, which holds a vector of `Point *` objects as its main data.  I want to iterate over the points the same way you would a vector, kind of like this:

```
for (vector<Point *>::iterator it = point_list->begin(); it != point_list->end(); ++it)
```

Clearly the begin() and end() functions I write can just return the vector's begin/end functions that they hold, but what is the return type of these functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood the question right, the answer is right in your question. You already use the return value and type of `begin` and `end` in your piece of code.

```
vector<Point *>::iterator it = point_list->begin();
```

clearly, `it` holds the return value of `begin()` and its type is well known:

```
vector<Point *>::iterator
```

---

By the way, a little off-topic - why `point_list` is pointer to vector, not an object? And second, why it's called list, as it's `vector`? Use `vector`, or `array`, or `sequence`, but not `list`, as it could be misleading. `list` is a STL container, different from `vector`.

Comment: It's a pointer to a vector so it doesn't get copied all over the place (as it will be a fairly large vector).  The PointList class is actually a singleton object, since I only want the one giant point list for the whole program, but it is passed around everywhere.  Thanks for the answer, I'll accept when the time is up :)

Comment: @4501: Consider researching how to work with references to avoid unneded copies.

Comment: O, I see, that makes sense :) I'm glad I helped and good luck :)

Comment: @K-ballo Is there a difference?  I've seen references used in this manner, but they seem to do the exact same thing..

Comment: @4501: What do you mean difference? You are missusing pointers to achieve the results that one would get from using references.

Comment: By the way, sorry for interrupting your conversation, but I think I'd use pointers, too. Probably some smart pointers, if necessary/possible. I don't say it's better, just sharing mu opinion :)

Comment: @4501: Use a smart pointer of some sort, or move-semantics if you can (C++11 only). Don't use a singleton, pass it to where it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

Their return type would be `vector<Point *>::iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

You should copy the container interface, by providing two iterator types, three `begin` functions and three `end` functions. The most obvious iterator types to use are taken straight from the vector:

```
struct PointList {
    typedef std::vector<Point*>::iterator iterator;
    typedef std::vector<Point*>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    iterator begin();
    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator cbegin() const;

    iterator end();
    const_iterator end() const;
    const_iterator cend() const;
};
```

`cbegin()` and `cend()` are new to C++11, they aren't in C++03. The idea is that since they don't have a non-const overload, the user can call them on a non-const container in preference to messing about with a conversion.

Since the underlying storage is in a vector, you might also consider providing `(c)rbegin()` and `(c)rend()`. In fact to implement the standard container interface you'd *have* to, since your iterator type is random-access. If you don't want to do that (perhaps because some future implementation of this class will not necessarily use a vector, but some other container underneath), then there is an argument for wrapping the vector's iterator in a class of your own just as you've wrapped the vector in a class of your own. That's extra work that's only needed if you need to prevent users from relying on properties of the iterator that could disappear in future implementations. You might not care about this in an internal API, more so in a published one.

Answer (score 0):

They are of type `vector<Point *>::iterator` just like your `it` object. But why do you want to iterate your data outside of the container object? That would be violation of encapsulation no?